How to bind coordinates to the Canvas Panel. WinUI
I am developing a program Win UI and I have encountered a binding problem. I need to display the readings of objects on the screen. They are placed in an arbitrary position. The data is stored in the database with values from 0 to 1.
I am using an ObservableCollection consisting of Silos objects. Each Silos object contains information, including coordinates on the visualization panel.
My problem is that the conversion or binding is not working correctly. All objects are located at the same point.
Here is an example of how it is and how it should be.


XAML
<local:ConvertPixel x:Key="ConwertToPixel"/>
...
<ItemsControl x:Name="CanvasPannel" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Siloses}"
              HorizontalAlignment ="Stretch"
              Height="700">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvasPannel, Path=Height}"
                    Width="{Binding ElementName=CanvasPannel, Path=Width}"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X, Converter={StaticResource ConwertToPixel}, ConverterParameter=1500}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y, Converter={StaticResource ConwertToPixel}, ConverterParameter=800}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="150"
                  Width="150">
                <Image x:Name="backgroundImage" Source="{Binding PathImageSilos, Mode=OneWay}" ></Image>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="18"></TextBlock>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,5,0">Max</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Max, Mode=OneWay}" ></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,5,0">Mid</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mid, Mode=OneWay}" ></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,5,0">Min</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Min, Mode=OneWay}" ></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

Conversion class
public class ConvertPixel : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (parameter != null)
        {
            return (int)((float)value * int.Parse((string)parameter));
        }
        else
            return (int)((float)value*1000);
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (int)value / (int)parameter;
    }
}

Thank you in advance.
I found a good example on a Russian-language website. https://habr.com/ru/articles/686438/
And of course I read articles from Microsoft.

Is the converter called for each item? Are the values that the converter receives and returns, correct?

Try adding a breakpoint in public class ConvertPixel : IValueConverter and checking the input and return in debug mode.

I was checking if the conversion was taking place. Added a Canvas to the DataTemplate in the Grid.Top and Canvas.Left. In the dynamic property Explorer, the values are correct, but there are no changes in the Canvas panel.

There an issue in the WinUI repo about this and it seems that Canvas is not working as an ItemsPanel.
Instead, you can try the CanvasView control from the CommunityToolkit-Labs. It's still an experimental control but you should take a look.
Here let me show you a basic sample code:
public partial class Item(object content, int x, int y) : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private object _content = content;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int _x = x;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int _y = y;
}


public partial class ShellViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Item> _items =
        [
            new Item("Item 1", 100, 50),
            new Item("Item 2", 200, 100),
            new Item("Item 3", 300, 150),
        ];
}

<Page
    ...
    xmlns:labs="using:CommunityToolkit.Labs.WinUI">
    <labs:CanvasView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items, Mode=OneWay}">
        <labs:CanvasView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
                <Button
                    Canvas.Left="{x:Bind X, Mode=OneWay}"
                    Canvas.Top="{x:Bind Y, Mode=OneWay}"
                    Content="{x:Bind Content, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </labs:CanvasView.ItemTemplate>
    </labs:CanvasView>
</Page>

In this answer, you can find the steps for experimental features from the CommunityToolkit-Labs.
You can find my working sample project here.
